# Circular dependency in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, circular-dependency

[This is my spreadsheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hbaQZl6Hl2XjXkmIAOXa6P_E7rVLuxsM2GSQ-q3EVNE/edit?usp=sharing)  I want to be able to set the cells in column B to something, skipping cells which are next to a column C cell which is not blank.  I want to use column C as a "custom entry" marker.  For example, if I put **X** in column C, then I will be able to type a custom entry into column B, but all the *other* cells in column B will be affected by the formula (in B1).

Formula:

`=arrayformula( if( row(A:A)=1, "DATES",IF(ISBLANK(C:C),"test",B:B)))`

Why am I getting a circular dependency error, and is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Besides the problem of having a circular dependency, the formula on the question will not work either when something be wrote on any cell on column B, so what is trying to be done it's not possible by using formulas.

The alternative could be the use a script.